hen attempting to run python setup.py develop for the Detectron project
the following error is encountered: ImportError: cannot import name '_nt_quote_args' from 'distutils.spawn
Error Context:
The error occurs during the build process when trying to compile the detectron2._C extension.
The environment is using Anaconda with a specific conda environment (detectron).
Steps Taken:
Installed g++ as it was initially identified as a missing dependency.
Verified the installation and configuration of the environment.
Checked for conflicts or inconsistencies in package versions.
Attempted to resolve potential issues with PyTorch compatibility by considering downgrading to an older version.
`× python setup.py develop did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [85 lines of output]
running develop
running egg_info
writing detectron2.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to detectron2.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
writing requirements to detectron2.egg-info\requires.txt
writing top-level names to detectron2.egg-info\top_level.txt
reading manifest file 'detectron2.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
adding license file 'LICENSE'
writing manifest file 'detectron2.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
running build_ext
building 'detectron2._C' extension
C:\Users\zalew\anaconda3\envs\detectron\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\develop.py:40: EasyInstallDeprecationWarning: easy_install command is deprecated.
!!
        ********************************************************************************
        Please avoid running ``setup.py`` and ``easy_install``.
        Instead, use pypa/build, pypa/installer or other
        standards-based tools.

        See https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/917 for details.
        ********************************************************************************

!!
  easy_install.initialize_options(self)
C:\Users\zalew\anaconda3\envs\detectron\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py:66: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated.
!!

        ********************************************************************************
        Please avoid running ``setup.py`` directly.
        Instead, use pypa/build, pypa/installer or other
        standards-based tools.

        See https://blog.ganssle.io/articles/2021/10/setup-py-deprecated.html for details.
        ********************************************************************************

!!
  self.initialize_options()
C:\Users\zalew\anaconda3\envs\detectron\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\cpp_extension.py:270: UserWarning: Error checking compiler version for cl: [WinError 2] Nie można odnaleźć określonego pliku
  warnings.warn('Error checking compiler version for {}: {}'.format(compiler, error))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 36, in <module>
  File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\zalew\detectron2\detectron2\setup.py", line 210, in <module>
    cmdclass={"build_ext": torch.utils.cpp_extension.BuildExtension},
  File "C:\Users\zalew\anaconda3\envs\detectron\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 107, in setup
    return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "C:\Users\zalew\anaconda3\envs\detectron\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 185, in setup
    return run_commands(dist)
  File "C:\Users\zalew\anaconda3\envs\detectron\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 201, in run_commands
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\Users\zalew\anaconda3\envs\detectron\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 969, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\Users\zalew\anaconda3\envs\detectron\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 1234, in run_command
    super().run_command(command)
  File "C:\Users\zalew\anaconda3\envs\detectron\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 988, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Users\zalew\anaconda3\envs\detectron\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\develop.py", line 34, in run
    self.install_for_development()
  File "C:\Users\zalew\anaconda3\envs\detectron\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\develop.py", line 111, in install_for_development
    self.run_command('build_ext')
  File "C:\Users\zalew\anaconda3\envs\detectron\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 318, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:\Users\zalew\anaconda3\envs\detectron\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 1234, in run_command
    super().run_command(command)
  File "C:\Users\zalew\anaconda3\envs\detectron\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 988, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Users\zalew\anaconda3\envs\detectron\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\build_ext.py", line 84, in run
    _build_ext.run(self)
  File "C:\Users\zalew\anaconda3\envs\detectron\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 345, in run
    self.build_extensions()
  File "C:\Users\zalew\anaconda3\envs\detectron\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\cpp_extension.py", line 649, in build_extensions
    build_ext.build_extensions(self)
  File "C:\Users\zalew\anaconda3\envs\detectron\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 467, in build_extensions
    self._build_extensions_serial()
  File "C:\Users\zalew\anaconda3\envs\detectron\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 493, in _build_extensions_serial
    self.build_extension(ext)
  File "C:\Users\zalew\anaconda3\envs\detectron\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\build_ext.py", line 246, in build_extension
    _build_ext.build_extension(self, ext)
  File "C:\Users\zalew\anaconda3\envs\detectron\lib\site-packages\Cython\Distutils\build_ext.py", line 135, in build_extension
    super(build_ext, self).build_extension(ext)
  File "C:\Users\zalew\anaconda3\envs\detectron\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 555, in build_extension
    depends=ext.depends,
  File "C:\Users\zalew\anaconda3\envs\detectron\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\cpp_extension.py", line 615, in win_wrap_ninja_compile
    from distutils.spawn import _nt_quote_args
ImportError: cannot import name '_nt_quote_args' from 'distutils.spawn' (C:\Users\zalew\anaconda3\envs\detectron\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\spawn.py)
[end of output]`

Do you guys know know to fix it ?
